# Existence theory for geometric flow of space curves

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, curves, flows, existence-theorems

Is there any existence theory applicable to general geometric flows of space curves in the following form?
$$
\partial_t \gamma = v_t t + v_n n + v_b b
$$
Here $\gamma$ is the evolving curve, $t$, $n$ and $b$ are the Frenet vectors and $v_t$, $v_n$ and $v_b$ are functions of the curvature $\kappa$ and torsion $\tau$.

I am familiar with results related to the curve shortening flow, where $v_n = \kappa$ and $v_b = 0$. But are there other examples with at least short time existence results?

Comment: Your question is perhaps a little bit too vague to give you completely satisfactory answer. Let me make a few comments, though: some functions (for example $v_n = -\kappa$) will make your problem [ill-posed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-posed_problem). Apart from the curve shortening flow, I believe e.g. the *elastic flow* is also actively studied. As far as I understand this is basically the 'curve analogue' of the [Willmore flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Willmore_energy#Willmore_flow).

Comment: See section 2 of Gage and Hamilton's "The heat equation shrinking convex plane curves" as an application of Hamilton's general short-time existence result in his "Three-manifolds with positive Ricci curvature." Other examples would follow in the same way

Comment: If $v_b=\kappa$ and $v_t=v_n=0$, then this is the vortex filament equation, which is a completely integrable dispersive equation.  (See http://iveyt.people.cofc.edu/papers/contemp3.pdf for other geometric flows of curves of this type).